Customize response from Pageable, Spring Boot(Kotlin)
I have an endpoint that uses pagination and Pageable and returns various information, I don't need all this information and I wanted to remove/add some. Is there a way to do this?
    @GetMapping
    fun getAll(
        @RequestParam(required = false) nameCourse: String?,
        pagination: Pageable
    ): Page<ResponseTopicDto> {
        return service.getAll(nameCourse,pagination)
    }

ResponseApi:
{
    "totalElements": 2,
    "totalPages": 2,
    "size": 1,
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "teste",
            "message": "MENSAGEM TITULO 1",
            "status": "NOT_ANSWERED",
            "date": "2024-06-24T21:06:05.61742"
        }
    ],
    "number": 1,
    "sort": {
        "empty": true,
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true
    },
    "first": false,
    "last": true,
    "numberOfElements": 1,
    "pageable": {
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "pageSize": 1,
        "sort": {
            "empty": true,
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true
        },
        "offset": 1,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "empty": false
}


Either

Create your own object that is constructed from a Page
Write your own JSON serializer for Page

